# How can I add a custom node into Navigation Pane of the Standard file open/save dialog?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

Our business has a document repository which can be connected to via a web service. Ideally, we would like to expose this repository through the standard file open/save dialogs in Windows.

Is it possible? Is there a template or sample code available (preferably in C#)?

I've marked (with a red rectangle) the area of the standard save dialog below in which I envisage the new node being added:

[image: Save Dialog]